# Remark 3.1.3 from Introduction to Representation Theory from Pavel Etingof

Tags: representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}$I'm trying to prove the following proposition (remark 3.1.3 from Introduction to Representation Theory from Pavel Etingof).

**Proposition.** 
*Any semisimple representation $V$ of $A$ is canonically identified with
$$\bigoplus_{X} \Hom_{A} (X,V) \otimes  X$$
where $X$ runs over all irreducible representations of $A$.*

So the book says I need to define the following map:
$$f:\bigoplus_{X} \Hom(X,V) \otimes X \rightarrow V : g\otimes x \mapsto  g(x).$$

where $x\in X, g\in \Hom(X,V)$.

But I honestly don't even get why this is a map, $g\otimes x$ doesn't seem in the domain to me. I would say that if $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ is the collection of irreducible representations of $A$. Then an element in the domain would look like $(g_i\otimes x_i)_{i\in I}$ where $g_i\in \Hom(X_i,V)$ and $x_i \in X_i$.

Comment: The definition of the map is analogous to defining a linear map on a basis; a general element of the domain is (or if you prefer, "can be thought of as") a sum of elements of the form $g\otimes x$. The map $f$ has to be linear, so $f\colon(g_i\otimes x_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto\sum_{i\in I}g_i(x_i)$.

Comment: @MattPressland Thanks, that makes sense, thanks for clearing it up. I will try to work with that definition.