# Subrepresentations of finite dimensional semisimple representations of an algebra

Tags: representation-theory

I'm following the notes by Prof. Etingof, linked [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf), and am stuck on a detail from Prop. 2.2, on page 23.

To briefly recap what is in the notes, we have a finite dimensional, semisimple representation $V=\oplus_i n_iV_i$ of an algebra $A$, where $\{V_i\}$ are pairwise nonisomorphic. We wish to show that any subrepresentation $W\subset V$ is of the form $\oplus_i r_iV_i$ for $r_i\le n_i$.

The proof takes an irreducible subrepresentation $P\subset W$, but I don't see how Schur's theorem implies that $P=V_i$ for some $i$, nor how the inclusion $P\hookrightarrow V$ factors through the $n_iV_i$ factor.

Any help filling in this detail here would be much appreciated!

Comment: This question is essentially the same as the question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958405/let-v-v-1%E2%8A%95-%E2%8B%AF-%E2%8A%95-v-n-be-semisimple-u-irreducible-show-that-dim-k-ho . The idea is that any morphism from $P$ to $V$ is just a choice of morphism from $P$ to each copy of $V_{i}$ in $V$ (think about the morphisms given by composing the original morphism to the projection map onto $V_{i}$.)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I didn't find that when I tried searching for related posts. I wonder if Kasper is in the same class I'm in...

Comment: Are you in Etingof's representation theory course?

Comment: Yep :) I take it you're not since it seems like you already know this stuff?

Comment: I'm not in the course, no. I'm working with him on some other stuff instead.