# Sub representations of a semisimple representation

Tags: representation-theory

In Etingof's [lecture note](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf) we have a proposition:
Let $V_i$, $1\leq i \leq m$ be irreducible finite dimensional pairwise nonisomorphic
representations of $A$, and $W$ be a subrepresentation of $V= {\oplus}^m_{i=1}n_iV_i$, then $W$ is isomorphic to ${\oplus}^m_{i=1}r_iV_i$, $r_i\leq n_i$.

My question is, what if we remove the condition "$V_i$ are finite dimensional"? Is this proposition still true, or there are counterexamples?

I was inspired by the problem [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964405/subrepresentations-of-finite-dimensional-semisimple-representations-of-an-algebr)

Comment: As long as it's a finite sum, it's true in any Abelian category.