# double centralizer theorem - decomposition of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am studying Schur-Weyl duality through the book [Introduction to Representation Theory](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/repb.pdf) and in theorem $5.18.1$

Theorem $5.18.1$: Let $A$, $B$ be two subalgebras of the algebra $\operatorname{End} E$ of endomorphisms of a finite dimensional vector space $E$, such that $A$ is semisimple and $B=\operatorname{End}_{A}E$. Then:

1. $A = \operatorname{End}_{B}E$;
2. $B$ is semisimple;
3. As a representation of $A \otimes B$, $E$ decomposes as
   $$E = \bigoplus_{i \in I}V_{i} \otimes W_{i}$$
   where $V_{i}$ are all the irreducible representations of $A$ e $W_{i}$ are all the irreducible representations of $B$. In particular, we have a natural bijection between irreducible representations of $A$ and $B$.

In the proof the author states that:

$$E = \bigoplus_{i \in I} V_{i} \otimes W_{i}$$
where $W_{i} := \operatorname{Hom}_{A}(V_{i}, E)$ and $A = \bigoplus_{i}\operatorname{End} V_{i}$,

but I can not understand how we can do this decomposition. Someone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The $A$-module $E$ decomposes canonically into isotypic components $\bigoplus_i E_i$, where $E_i$ is defined to be the sum of all submodules of $E$ isomorphic to $V_i$. The sum the author has is essentially a different way of writing this decomposition down.

Comment: @Joppi Sorry, but i dont know what is isotypic components

Comment: The definition is right there: if $V$ is an irreducible module, and $E$ is any module, then the $V$-isotypic component of $E$ is the sum of all submodules isomorphic to $V$.

Comment: I'm very confused because I don't have many requirements. In fact, I was thinking of using this kind of decomposition described here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956788/remark-3-1-3-from-introduction-to-representation-theory-from-pavel-etingof)

Comment: but I can't see $E$ as an $A$-module, only $EndE$

Comment: $\newcommand{\End}{\mathrm{End}\,}$If $A$ and $B$ are subalgebras of $\End E$, then $E$ is both an $A$- and a $B$-module. For an $R$-module structure on $V$ defines a ring homomorphism $R \to \End V$ by $r \mapsto (v \mapsto rv)$, and conversely such a ring homomorphism $\varphi: R \to\End V$ gives a module structure on $V$ by $r\cdot v = \varphi(r) (v)$.

Comment: So, knowing that $E$ is an $A$-module, I can use this decomposition (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956788/remark-3-1-3-from-introduction-to-representation-theory-from-pavel-etingof) to conclude the author's statement?